# 403 Forbidden error when open the next js site with http

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iis, next.js

When I want to open the Next.JS website was deployed on IIS with HTTP address, I get this error:

> Get http://...../_next/static/chunks/webpack-73760e2208a549db.js net::
> ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden)

But when I open the website with HTTPS I can open it!?

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue on Ubuntu Server/Nginx.I configured `OpenSSL` certification and the issue solved.